# Swift 4 mapkit reloads map after hiding map annotations

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

I got two viewcontrollers that displays a mapkit and one for places description that have a back button. But every time I try to hide a map annotation and go to places description and then back again to mapkit it reloads my map with the annotation I try to hide. How do i prevent a mapkit from reloading its data but still hide my map annotations?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        //1
        let coordinate = view.annotation!.coordinate
        //2
        if let userCoordinate = userLocation {
            //3
            if userCoordinate.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)) < 30000 {
                //4

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ARViewController") as?    PlaceViewController {
                    // more code later
                    //5
                    if let mapAnnotation = view.annotation as? MapA {
                        //6
                        if(mapAnnotation.title == "New")
                        {
                         mapView.view(for: mapAnnotation)?.isHidden = true
                            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            viewController.adL.text = "TEST"
                       viewController.descT.text = "Hej"



                        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It reloads because here

```
mapView.view(for: mapAnnotation)?.isHidden = true
```

You explicitly call it to reload

you can directly do

```
view.isHidden = true
```

as you catch the view here

```
didSelect view: MKAnnotationView
```

that is currently selected

Comment: I have changed to view.isHidden = true, but Its still reloading my map after I press back.

Comment: Do you have any code inside viewDidAppear Or viewWillAppear ?

Comment: No, only code in viewDidLoad in places viewcontroller. But before I present my viewcontroller i see that my map annotations isHidden until I press back button.

Comment: I also tried    selectedAnnotation = view.annotation
                            mapView.removeAnnotation(selectedAnnotation!) but still the same error. Any other suggestions?